# Extracting META using PHP simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php, html

I have read and tried every POST about this but cannot get it to work.
This is the HTML:

```
<meta itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserPlays:4635">
<meta itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserLikes:4">
<meta itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserComments:0">
```

I need to extract the '4635' bit.

Code:

```
<?php
  $html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find("meta[name=interactionCount]")->getAttribute('content') as $element) {
    $val = $element->innertext; 

    echo '<br>Value is: '.$val; 
}
```

I get nothing back?

Comment: you can look up manual link http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I have used this for all other HTML elements I needed, but just could not figure out this last one. Thanks for comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$metaData= '<meta itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserPlays:4635">
            <meta itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserLikes:4">
            <meta itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserComments:0">';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($metaData);
$metas = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');

foreach($metas as $el) {
  list($user_param,$value) = explode(':',$el->getAttribute('content'));
  // here check what you need
  print $user_param.' '.$value.'<br/>';
}

// OUTPUT 

UserPlays 4635

UserLikes 4

UserComments 0
```

Comment: It is not related to Question! Beacasue it does not use simple_html_dom .php.

Answer (score 1):

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$url = '...';
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach ($html->find('meta[itemprop="interactionCount"]') as $element) {
    list($key, $value) = explode(':', strval($key->content));
    echo 'Value:'.$value."\n";
}
```

Comment: php 'split' function is depreciated so this did not work. Thanks for the input though.